# Рисование линии через mousePressEvent и mouseReleaseEvent

Tags: qt, c++

Всем привет)

Есть две кнопки на форме, QPushButton1 и QPushButton2. Мне надо нарисовать линию между кнопками. Т.е. нажали на кнопку QPushButton1 и нажатой навели на кнопку QPushButton2 и там отжали. И потом на форме должна рисоваться линия. Как это реализовать? Желательно после рисования линии QPushButton1 и QPushButton2 сбрасывались.

При отжатии QPushButton2 почему то реагирует только в своей области кнопки. Т.е. нажали на кнопку QPushBUtton2 и там же отжали, только так отжатие срабатывает.

**1)Правильно ли делаю каждый раз update()?**

**2)Почему отжатие кнопки работает только в своей области?**

Answer (score 1):

Сам код

```
void Dialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    if (_isBeingMouse1 &&_isBeingMouse2 == true)
    {
        QPainter p(this); // Создаём новый объект рисовальщика

        p.setPen(Qt::red);// Настройки рисования
        p.setBrush(Qt::white);// Настройки рисования
        // p.drawLine(10,10,100,100); // Рисование линии
        // painter->drawLine(firstTextWidget.geometry().center(),secondTextWidget.geometry().center());
        p.drawLine(ui->pushButton->geometry().center(),ui->pushButton_2->geometry().center());
    }
    else
    {
        //QPainter painter(this);
        //qDebug()<< "text";
    }
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    if(_isBeingMouse1 == true)
        _isBeingMouse1 = false;
    else
        _isBeingMouse1 = true;
    update();
}

void Dialog::on_pushButton_2_released()
{
    if(_isBeingMouse2 == true)
        _isBeingMouse2 = false;
    else
        _isBeingMouse2 = true;
    update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Доброго времени суток!

По-поводу метода `update()` (из документации):

> This function does not cause an
> immediate repaint; instead it
> schedules a paint event for processing
> when Qt returns to the main event
> loop. This permits Qt to optimize for
> more speed and less flicker than a
> call to repaint() does.

Исходя из этих слов от того что вы делаете `update()` в слоте обрабатывающем нажатие на кнопку, никакого особо эффекта, т.е. форма будет перерисована когда цикл сообщений дойдет до `paintEvent()`, *в целом ничего страшного* вы не делаете. Вызывать `repaint()` внутри paintEvent() крайне не рекомендуется (программа войдет в бесконечный цикл).

По поводу отжатия: если в двух словах, то так задумано самим фреймворком, то что вы хотите сделать лучше делать используя слот `toggle()` и свойства `down`, `check` и `checked`

Ну и наконец самое главное: посмотрите пример [Diagram Scene Example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview-diagramscene.html) из поставки Qt, там почти то что Вы хотите: рисование линий между двумя объектами (даже со стрелочками).

Я думаю, если заменить объекты, которые есть в примеры на наследников  QGraphicsWidget или QGraphicsProxyWidget, то все должно получиться!